# Code keeps on running - what did I do wrong?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code where if the first column is "Forecast", it populates a quick calculation. If "Actual", it takes actual formula and pastes it for rest. This only needs to happen for 3 columns on the page. However, as I run this code it keeps running with no end in sight. What did I do wrong?

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double
Dim b As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")

a = 0#
b = 0#
c = 0#

For b = 2 To 13
If sht.Cells(1, b).Value = "Forecast" Then
    a = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dOSO.Value) / 1000000
    b = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dSYN.Value) / 1000000
    c = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dRM.Value) / 1000000
    sht.Cells(6, b) = a
    sht.Cells(11, b) = a
    sht.Cells(28, b) = a
ElseIf sht.Cells(1, b).Value = "Actual" Then
    sht.Cells(6, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(6, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    sht.Cells(11, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(11, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    sht.Cells(28, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(28, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next b
```

Comment: you are redefining **b** inside the For b = 2 To 13 loop. apparently (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dSYN.Value) / 1000000 never reaches 13.

Comment: Thanks! fixed it.

Comment: post your solution below and you can accept it as the answer in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Dim a As Double, bb As Double, c As Double
Dim b As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")

a = 0#
bb = 0#
c = 0#

For b = 2 To 13
If sht.Cells(1, b).Value = "Forecast" Then
    a = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dOSO.Value) / 1000000 
    bb = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dSYN.Value) / 1000000 
    c = (Me.dAECO.Value * Me.dRM.Value) / 1000000 
    sht.Cells(6, b) = a
    sht.Cells(11, b) = bb
    sht.Cells(28, b) = c
ElseIf sht.Cells(1, b).Value = "Actual" Then
    sht.Cells(6, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(6, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    sht.Cells(11, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(11, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    sht.Cells(28, 2).Copy
    sht.Cells(28, b).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next b

End Sub
```